# Jquery ajaxSubmit plugin form input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, plugins

In my website I have a form which contains more than one file input fields. The first one is:

```
<input type="file" name="questionimages[]" multiple />
```

I use this one to upload multiple images. The next ones are:

```
<input type="file" name="optionimages1" />
<input type="file" name="optionimages2" />
<input type="file" name="optionimages3" />
...
<input type="file" name="optionimagesn" />
```

The number of these input fields varies depending on user input. All except the first input fields are inserted dynamically by the user, I basically use jquery and use the `html` method to insert a new input field every time the user clicks a button, and the name of the input fields changes by adding and incrementally bigger value at the end of the name of the input filed, so I can distinguish it from the rest.

I am using the Jquery form plugin to upload the images through ajax using the `ajaxSubmit` function.

The problem is, when the user clicks the respective button to insert a new input, that new input filed has the name attribute equal to `questionimages[]` which is the name of the first input field, which is always there regardless of the user input. Even though I write something like:

```
$('#someID').html('<input type="file" name="optionimages1" />');
```

The input field gets the name `questionimages[]` instead of the name `optionimages1`. What is causing this? Is the Jquery form plugin automatically overwriting the name values of the newly inserted input tags?

NOTE: I want to add images from the dynamically added fields so I can distinguish them from the images uploaded through the first input field with PHP, that is why I don't use the first input field to upload all of the images. The first input field can add multiple images if it wants, but the ones added through the other input fields are images that I need for another purpose so I need to distinguish them from the images uploaded through the first input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the way you are adding the fields. However if you want to manualy set the name of the field you can always use:

```
$("#newfield").attr("name","theNameIWant");
```

to change the attribute "name" of the input field.
You can also select the last input field like this:

```
$(".container input:last")
```

That way you can alter only the newly added field without having to set an ID